# Finding opening and closing price using sqlite GROUP BY statement (accessing main query alias in subquery)

Tags: sqlite

I want to preface this post by saying that I am a SQL(ite) newbie. My main goal is to find the opening/closing/high/low/average prices of each 5 minute interval of these stock prices. I can get the high/low working with min/max and the group by query but I am running into problems with the opening/closing. My database looks something like this

```
SYMBOL | DATETIME           |PRICE
AAPL   | 1999-06-01 09:30:01|45.0
AAPL   | 1999-06-01 09:30:03|44.9375
AAPL   | 1999-06-01 09:30:04|44.9375
AAPL   | 1999-06-01 09:30:05|44.9375
AAPL   | 1999-06-01 09:30:06|44.9375
AAPL   | 1999-06-01 09:30:07|45.0
AAPL   | 1999-06-01 09:30:08|45.0
AAPL   | 1999-06-01 09:30:09|44.9375
AAPL   | 1999-06-01 09:30:11|45.0
AAPL   | 1999-06-01 09:30:12|44.96875
```

The following query

```
SELECT SYMBOL, MIN(DATETIME) AS MINDT, MAX(DATETIME) AS MAXDT, AVG(PRICE)
FROM stocks
WHERE DATETIME < '1999-06-02 00:00:00'
GROUP BY strftime('%s', DATETIME)/(60*5) LIMIT 4;
```

results in

```
AAPL|1999-06-01 09:30:01|1999-06-01 09:34:41|44.9269724822695
AAPL|1999-06-01 09:35:22|1999-06-01 09:39:58|44.8615196078431
AAPL|1999-06-01 09:40:03|1999-06-01 09:44:58|44.9800531914894
AAPL|1999-06-01 09:45:05|1999-06-01 09:49:52|44.9397321428571
```

whereas

```
SELECT SYMBOL, MIN(DATETIME) AS MINDT, MAX(DATETIME) AS MAXDT, AVG(PRICE),
(SELECT PRICE FROM stocks WHERE DATETIME=MINDT),
(SELECT PRICE FROM stocks WHERE DATETIME=MAXDT)
FROM stocks
WHERE DATETIME < '1999-06-02 00:00:00'
GROUP BY strftime('%s', DATETIME)/(60*5);
```

throws this error in SQL

```
Error: near "MINDT": syntax error
```

and in R

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such column: MINDT
```

I have googled around and I think I found what is wrong with my query: you can not acces an alias made in main query in a sub query (i.e. reference MINDT in the subquery). But my I lack SQL knowledge to find a fix to this. Is there anyone that could help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first query is OK although not entirely correct.

- You need to be careful with `GROUP BY` and not have any column in the `SELECT` list that is not also in the `GROUP BY` list. So, add the `symbol` in the group by list.
- Next, the `LIMIT` needs an `ORDER BY` so you are 100% certain that you get always the same results. SQLite (and many other DBMS) may return the same results all the time but that "all the time" is not guaranteed. You never know when you'll get a different execution plan and weird result.
- If you want more aggregate results (like minimum or maximum price) over the windows, you can add them in the list.

The query becomes:

```
SELECT symbol, 
       MIN(datetime) AS mindt, 
       MAX(datetime) AS maxdt, 
       AVG(price)    AS avg_price,
       MIN(price)    AS min_price,
       MAX(price)    AS max_price
FROM stocks
WHERE datetime < '1999-06-02 00:00:00'
GROUP BY symbol, strftime('%s', DATETIME)/(60*5) 
ORDER BY symbol, strftime('%s', DATETIME)/(60*5)
LIMIT 4 ;
```

Now to get also the first and the last price ("opening" and "closing" in finance terminology) in these 5-minutes windows, you'll either need window functions or correlated subqueries or to wrap this query in a derived table and then join again to the original table. I'll write the 3rd option.

It assumes there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(symbol, datetime)` or (even without a constraint) that you don't have 2 rows with same symbol and datetime:

```
SELECT 
    s.*,
    s1.price AS opening_price,
    s2.price AS closing_price
FROM
  ( SELECT symbol, 
           MIN(datetime) AS mindt, 
           MAX(datetime) AS maxdt, 
           AVG(price)    AS avg_price,
           MIN(price)    AS min_price,
           MAX(price)    AS max_price
    FROM stocks
    WHERE datetime < '1999-06-02 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY symbol, strftime('%s', DATETIME)/(60*5) 
    ORDER BY symbol, strftime('%s', DATETIME)/(60*5)
    LIMIT 4
  ) AS s
  LEFT JOIN
    stocks AS s1
      ON  s.symbol = s1.symbol
      AND s.mindt  = s1.datetime
  LEFT JOIN
    stocks AS s2
      ON  s.symbol = s2.symbol
      AND s.maxdt  = s2.datetime ;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! edit: enter doesn't work here, guess it's shift enter. The comma after "    s2.price AS last_price," should be removed, right? I ran the query and even for the first day it took quite some time. I think that the query works but I don't understand it fully yet. What does LEFT JOIN exactly do here?

Comment: It could `INNER JOIN`, it makes no difference. These joins are there so we can get the related price values (first and last)

Comment: When I put in the query I this is one row for example "AAPL|1999-06-01 09:30:01|1999-06-01 09:34:41|44.9269724822695|45.0|44.8125". I only see SYMBOL/mindt/maxdt and then 3 numbers. Where are the min/max?

Comment: do you want the highest and lowest prices in the (5-min) window? Or the and the last prices (in that window)?

Comment: Both. My goal is to use the min/max/opening/closing/average price in the 5 minute interval for further use.

Comment: Then you need to add those (min and max price) in the derived table. Editing

Answer (score 2):

With correlated subqueries, it would look like this:

```
SELECT Symbol,
       MIN(DateTime) AS MinDT,
       MIN(Price) AS MinPrice,
       MAX(Price) AS MaxPrice,
       AVG(Price) AS AvgPrice,
       (SELECT Price
        FROM stocks AS s2
        WHERE s2.Symbol   = stock.Symbol
          AND s2.DateTime = MIN(stocks.DateTime)
       ) AS OpeningPrice,
       (SELECT Price
        FROM stocks AS s2
        WHERE s2.Symbol   = stock.Symbol
          AND s2.DateTime = MAX(stocks.DateTime)
       ) AS ClosingPrice
FROM stocks
WHERE DateTime < '1999-06-02 00:00:00'
GROUP BY Symbol,
         strftime('%s', DateTime)/(60*5)
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 4;
```